# Set root for PHP in nginx

Tags: php, nginx

How to set absolute docroot for php on nginx (1.12.2)?

```
<?php 
die(print_r(getcwd(), TRUE)); 
?>
```

gives me /var/www/mydomain.com

I want to set mydomain.com as docroot then be able to use '/' ex.

```
include '/css/style.css';
```

now I have to use

```
include '/var/www/mydomain.com/css/style.css';
```

My nginx conf

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name mydomain.com;
    root /var/www/mydomain.com/;
    index index.php index.html index.htm;

    error_page 404 /404.html;

   location ~ \.php$ {
        try_files $uri =404;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.1-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME /var/www/mydomain.com$fastcgi_script_name;
        include fastcgi_params;
    }

    location ~ /\.ht {
        deny  all;
    }

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
    }
}
```

Is it any good practice to set all site files in public or html folder (/var/www/mydomain.com/public)?

Comment: `I want to set mydomain.com as docroot then be able to use '/' ex.` that's not really how it works.. `/` is the root folder, not the web root of your web server.

Comment: just use `__DIR__` to get the absolute path of the file where you are in, an navigate from it.

Comment: I wan't to use `__DIR__`
When i had hosting i can use '/'

Comment: @Widziks your question is not clear ! what do you want exactly ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are running `php-fpm`, you can set `chroot` in the config and restrict it to a certain directory. See the below thread for more details

https://serverfault.com/questions/344538/php-fpms-chroot-and-chdir-directory

> **chroot string**
>
> Chroot to this directory at the start. This value must be defined as an absolute path. When this value is not set, chroot is not used.
>
> **chdir string**
>
> Chdir to this directory at the start. This value must be an absolute path. Default value: current directory or / when chroot.

https://secure.php.net/manual/en/install.fpm.configuration.php

So you will add the below to the your php-fpm config

```
chroot=/var/www/mydomain.com
chdir=/
```